Как получить данные с лимитом
Есть мой  рабочий запрос к базе данных, его я покажу ниже, собственно проблема такая: как мне добавить limit и offset к моему запросу?
рабочий запрос :
 const vinyls = await this.vinylRepository.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Review,
          as: 'reviews',
          attributes: [],
        },
      ],
      attributes: {
        include: [
          [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('reviews.review')), 'avgRating'],
        ],
      },
      raw: true,
      group: ['Vinyl.id'],
    });

Этот запрос  отдаёт мне все данные без ошибок. Но если же я добавляю offset/limit вот так , будет ошибка :
  const limit = 10;
  const offset = 10;

  const vinyls = await this.vinylRepository.findAll({
      
      include: [
        {
          model: Review,
          as: 'reviews',
          attributes: [],
        },
      ],
      attributes: {
        include: [
          [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('reviews.review')), 'avgRating'],
        ],
      },
      raw: true,
      group: ['Vinyl.id'],
      limit,
      offset
    });

Ошибка :

[Nest] 25428  - 04/28/2024, 9:36:11 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown column 'reviews.review' in 'field list'
Error:
at Query.run (G:\React\internship_of_leverx\final\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:25)

nestjs/mysql/sequelize

какой sql генерирует orm?

@nörbörnën  вот код с ошибкой : Executing (default): SELECT Vinyl.* FROM (SELECT Vinyl.id, Vinyl.name, Vinyl.price, Vinyl.author, Vinyl.description, Vinyl.createdAt, Vinyl.updatedAt, AVG(reviews.review) AS avgRating FROM vinyl AS Vinyl GROUP BY Vinyl.id LIMIT 10, 10) AS Vinyl LEFT OUTER JOIN review AS reviews ON Vinyl.id = reviews.vinylId;

@nörbörnën вот код  без лимитов : Executing (default): SELECT Vinyl.id, Vinyl.name, Vinyl.price, Vinyl.author, Vinyl.description, Vinyl.createdAt, Vinyl.updatedAt, AVG(reviews.review) AS avgRating FROM vinyl AS Vinyl LEFT OUTER JOIN review AS reviews ON Vinyl.id = reviews.vinylId GROUP BY Vinyl.id;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474954/4496422

@nörbörnën спасибо вам большое. если вы оформите ответ как отдельный комментарий , то я его помечу как ответ.P/S я уже и надежду потерял)

вы знаете о проблеме и решении больше меня, так что напишите ответ сами

 const vinyls = await this.vinylRepository.findAll({
  subQuery: false, 
  include: [
    {
      model: Review,
      as: 'reviews',
      attributes: [],
    },
  ],
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('reviews.review')), 'avgRating'],
    ],
  },
  raw: true,
  limit,
  offset,
  group: ['Vinyl.id'],
});

